# No records inserting using WHILE function to generate multiple new records

Tags: sql-server

First time using the WHILE function in SQL. I've been through a lot of posts trying to figure out what I am doing wrong but have not found it yet.

```
DECLARE @BeginTagNo INT
        SELECT @BeginTagNo = (SELECT MIN(BEGINTAGNO) FROM dbo.INLoadTagReconciliation WHERE BEGINTAGNO <> 0 AND TYPE = 1 AND TRACTCODE = '00099-023-F')
DECLARE @EndTagNo INT
        SELECT @EndTagNo = (SELECT MAX(ENDTAGNO) FROM dbo.INLoadTagReconciliation WHERE ENDTAGNO <> 0 AND TYPE = 1 AND TRACTCODE = '00099-023-F')
DECLARE @id INT
        SELECT @BeginTagNo = (SELECT MIN(BEGINTAGNO) FROM dbo.INLoadTagReconciliation WHERE BEGINTAGNO <> 0 AND TYPE = 1 AND TRACTCODE = '00099-023-F')     

WHILE @id >= @BeginTagNo and @id <= @EndTagNo

BEGIN
    insert INTO workINLoadTagReconciliation values(@id,null,null)
    select @id = @id+1
END
```

When I run the above, nothing is ever entered into the table. 
When you run this:

```
SELECT @BeginTagNo = (SELECT MIN(BEGINTAGNO) FROM dbo.INLoadTagReconciliation WHERE BEGINTAGNO <> 0 AND TYPE = 1 AND TRACTCODE = '00099-023-F')
```

You are returned 2021901.

When you run this:

```
SELECT @EndTagNo = (SELECT MAX(ENDTAGNO) FROM dbo.INLoadTagReconciliation WHERE ENDTAGNO <> 0 AND TYPE = 1 AND TRACTCODE = '00099-023-F')
```

You are returned 2022600. And the @id variable is the same as @BeginTagNo. I am hoping to have a table generated from this that has 699 rows going from 2021901 to 2022600. Can anyone shed some light on my stupidity.

Comment: `@id` is never assigned a value, therefore your `WHILE` condition is always false.

Comment: Thank you for that. You were my second set of eyes. I was correct in the "my stupidity" part. Cheers!

Comment: Why are you using a `WHILE` in the first place? A tally would be far quicker.

Comment: Thanks Larnu, I am going to start researching that now. This is my first attempt on this specific job. I do not think while will work for me because I need this to happen many more time based on a grouping. Maybe Tally will get me there. Anyways, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Ok, will do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the looping. 
Try;

```
INSERT INTO workINLoadTagReconciliation 
SELECT BEGINTAGNO, NULL, NULL
FROM dbo.INLoadTagReconciliation
WHERE BEGINTAGNO >= 
    (SELECT MIN(BEGINTAGNO) FROM dbo.INLoadTagReconciliation 
      WHERE BEGINTAGNO <> 0 AND TYPE = 1 AND TRACTCODE = '00099-023-F')
AND BEGINTAGNO <= 
    (SELECT MAX(ENDTAGNO) FROM dbo.INLoadTagReconciliation 
      WHERE ENDTAGNO <> 0 AND TYPE = 1 AND TRACTCODE = '00099-023-F')
```

Comment: You are assuming that there is one and only one record for each convective integer between the beginning and ending range of `BEGINTAGNO` in the table `INLoadTagReconciliation`.

Comment: Your right. I made that assumption based on his statement "I am hoping to have a table generated from this that has 699 rows going from 2021901 to 2022600." but if that is not the case then a Tally table or function would be the proper solution.